# entity was modified, but it won't be updated because the property is immutable

Tags: java

With JPA, there is no storage problem, but the following warning is used when modifying:

```
HHH000502: The [umsMember] property of the [com.trustasia.cloudpki.entity.CmsBatchEnroll] entity was modified, but it won't be updated because the property is immutable.
```

The entity class information is as follows:

```
@ManyToOne(targetEntity = UmsMember.class)
@JoinColumn(name = "member_id", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
@NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
private UmsMember umsMember;
```

I want to know what this warning is all about and how to get rid of it

Comment: What does this have to do with security? Seems to be a general programming question about a particular framework.

Comment: you won't get that message if you stop trying to modify immutable things.

Comment: Are you attempting to change the field to point to another UmsMember? The annotation @JoinColumn explicitly states `updatable = false`.

Comment: I didn't change anything about umsMember, I changed a field in CMS batchenroll, and I don't know why

Answer (score -1):

Add these in `UmsMember` class

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private List<CmsBatchEnroll> cmsBatchEnrolls = new ArrayList<>();
```

The key point is `cascade=CascadeType.ALL`, it makes an entity mutable.